# exiting full screen flutter web

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart

I use the flowing code to enter full screen,
could some one help me , how I can catch exit full screen event in the flutter side.

```
   import 'dart:html';
   void goFullScreen() {
   document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
      }
```

Comment: To detect exiting from full screen mode, you can use this if statement: if (!document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement)

Comment: M Karimi  could show me sample dart code ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you got the answer. Maybe this will help someone else.

```
 import 'dart:html';

  void exitFullScreen() {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }
```

Hope that helps.